# Determine the big O running time

Tags: algorithm

I am struggling with this question would like some help , thank you.

Determine the big O running time of the method myMethod() by counting the
approximate number of operations it performs. Show all details of your answer.
Note: the symbol % represent a modulus operator, that is, the remainder of a
number divided by another number.

```
      ℎ([], ) {
       ← 0
        ← 0   − 1 {
          ←    − 1 {
           ← + []
           ← 1
          ℎ ( <  + 2) {
             (%2 == 0) {
               =  + 1
            }
             + +
          }
        }
      }
     
    }
```

Comment: I formatted your code and added a `+` to the `while` condition, otherwise it wouldn't make sense. It doesn't change the time complexity though.

Comment: The inner loop always executes n+1 iterations, and it is performed n + n-1 + n-2 + ... 1 times.

Comment: Isn't this just `O(n^3)`

Answer (score 2):

The outer for loop with the variable `i` runs `n` times.

The inner for loop with the variable `j` runs `n - i` times for each iteration of the outer loop. This would make the inner loop run `n + n-1 + n-2 +...+ 1` times in aggregation which is the equivalent of `n * (n+1) / 2`.

The `while` loop inside the inner `for` loop runs `n + 1` times for each iteration of the inner `for` loop.

This makes the while loop to run `(n * (n+1) / 2) * (n + 2)`. This produces `(n^2 + n) / 2 * (n + 2) = (n^2 + n) * (n + 2) / 2 = (n^3 + 2n^2 + n^2 + 2n) / 2 = (n^3 + 3n^2 + 2n) / 2)`.

Dropping lower degrees of `n` and constants we get `O(n^3)`.

You could have also argued that `n + n-1 + ... + 1` is `O(n^2)` times a linear operation becomes `O(n^3)`. Which would have been more intuitive and faster.

Comment: while n+1 times.

Comment: right, good catch @YvesDaoust thanks